# log() without console or math prefix?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently going through the [MDN page on Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events#Example), and I'm working with this code here:

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:solid black 1px;">
  Your browser does not support canvas element.
</canvas>
<br>
<button onclick="startup()">Initialize</button>
<br>
Log: <pre id="log" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"></pre>
```

**JS**

```
function startup() {
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
  el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
  log("initialized.");
}
```

[Here's a Code Pen with the code above.](https://codepen.io/rpivovar/pen/GxMymB?editors=1010#)

I've actually never seen a `log()` like this without the `console` or `Math` prefix before it, and I'm expecting it to produce some result here, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything in the Code Pen when you click the button to fire the function `startup()`. I also did some searching about this and weirdly didn't seem to find anything. `log()` is used in other places on the MDN page as well.

Can anyone shed light on how this works, or share resources for this that I'm just not finding?

Comment: This CodePen doesn't work for me. `log()` alone doesn't work either.

Comment: The code pen should be an exact copy from the MDN page - I'm not understanding what the `log()` is supposed to be doing in their code..

Comment: I'll take a wild guess and say it's just a typo, there are quite a few on MDN's examples.

Comment: I'm guessing it's supposed to print "initialized." into the inner HTML of the `pre` element, but it's not doing that, and doesn't seem to be doing anything, nor can I find any resources on it

Comment: hmm yeah maybe it's just psuedo code

Comment: I took a further look on the MDN page, turns out the function is defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `log` function is defined [later on the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events#Showing_what's_going_on) :

```
function log(msg) {
  var p = document.getElementById('log');
  p.innerHTML = msg + "\n" + p.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: holy crap you're right. A long way down from the initial code. jeez

Answer (score 1):

It is not a typo. If you go through the whole tutorial, you can see this piece of code:

```
function log(msg) {
  var p = document.getElementById('log');
  p.innerHTML = msg + "\n" + p.innerHTML;
}
```

The subsection is called **Showing what's going on** and appears near the 2/3 of the page. Search for the subsection's name to find the `log()` code.